# how to fix fatal error: gd.h: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, make

I am trying to install some software called CRISPResso on my mac using `sudo pip install`. When I type the command `CRISPResso --help` I get the following message.

> You need to install and have the command #####needle##### in your PATH variable to use CRISPResso!

I next installed EMBOSS-6.6.0 which contains needle, after doing `./configure` followed by `make` I get the following error

```
Making install in plplot
Making install in lib
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 ../.././install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/share/EMBOSS'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 plstnd5.fnt plxtnd5.fnt '/usr/local/share/EMBOSS'
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../ajax/core  -I../ajax/core -I/usr/X11/include -I./ -I/usr/include/gd -DPREFIX=\"/usr/local\" -DBUILD_DIR=\".\" -DDRV_DIR=\".\" -DEMBOSS_TOP=\"/Users/hc/Downloads/EMBOSS-6.6.0\" -DAJ_MACOSXLF  -O2  -I/usr/X11/include -MT gd.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/gd.Tpo -c -o gd.lo gd.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../ajax/core -I../ajax/core -I/usr/X11/include -I./ -I/usr/include/gd -DPREFIX=\"/usr/local\" -DBUILD_DIR=\".\" -DDRV_DIR=\".\" -DEMBOSS_TOP=\"/Users/hc/Downloads/EMBOSS-6.6.0\" -DAJ_MACOSXLF -O2 -I/usr/X11/include -MT gd.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/gd.Tpo -c gd.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/gd.o
gd.c:127:16: fatal error: gd.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [gd.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I have also tried `sudo make install` and I get the same error.

Any suggestions on what is going wrong here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to install the GD library (http://www.libgd.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The following bit of output:

```
fatal error: gd.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

Is telling you that you are missing a header file required by the program.  In C programs, header files typically contain function declarations and other bits of code that describe the API of a library being used by that program.

In this case gd.h belongs to libgd.  How to get this depends on your operating system.  You often need to install two packages, 1 for the shared library and another for the headers (libgd and libgd-devel for example).